# Why do I need to put any random string as a function parameter to make my function work?

Tags: function, parameters, scope

I´m having trouble understanding the function parameters of subFunction1, subFunction2 and subFunction3 in the code below. It seems myBigFunction() works regardless, as long as I put any random string inside the parenthesis (something, nothing and anything in the code below). How come it works, even though I´ve just put in 3 function parameters that don´t have any relation to any code elsewhere? Why do I need to put any random text here?

```
function myBigFunction() {
    var myValue = 1;

    subFunction1(myValue);
    subFunction2(myValue);
    subFunction3(myValue);
  }

  function subFunction1(something) {
    console.log(something);
  }

  function subFunction2(nothing) {
    console.log(nothing);
  }

  function subFunction3(anything) {
    console.log(anything);
  }
```

Comment: Show your random string in the code.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I´ve used the wrong terminology. Notice the words I´ve put in the parenthesis of the bottom three functions (in subFunction1 I´ve put in 'something', in subFunction2 I´ve put in 'nothing', and in subFunction3 I´ve put in 'anything'). Why do these have to be here? How do they relate to the rest of the code? I find it hard to understand since I can call them anything, and the code will still work...

Comment: This is not a string... it's a variable, which receives whatever value you pass in when calling the function. This is why it can have different names.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for clarifying this for me =)